# How to get two values

Tags: regex, grafana

I`m trying to create variable in Grafana and get two values from one long string.
Query result is:

```
ifHCInOctets{ifAlias="string1",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 22 on Unit 1",ifIndex="int2",ifName="0x3232"}
```

And I need to get string1 and int2 in one result.
I try this regex, but in grafana I get only string1:

```
.*ifAlias="(.*?)",.*,ifIndex="([1-25][^"]*).*
```

upd:

The goal is to get port index and ifAlias in graph title. The raw data is:

```
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="UPSTREAM",ifDescr="",ifIndex="4",ifName="4"} 9.3057114067485e+13
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="",ifIndex="5",ifName="5"} 2.274143681e+09
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="",ifIndex="6",ifName="6"} 7.002508461736e+12
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 10 on Unit 1",ifIndex="10",ifName="10"} 2.577610903151e+12
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 15 on Unit 1",ifIndex="15",ifName="15"} 4.854219613e+10
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 16 on Unit 1",ifIndex="16",ifName="16"} 4.96070449818e+11
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 17 on Unit 1",ifIndex="17",ifName="17"} 1.9350264954065e+13
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 18 on Unit 1",ifIndex="18",ifName="18"} 3.3384544298231e+13
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 19 on Unit 1",ifIndex="19",ifName="19"} 3.668765293115e+12
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 20 on Unit 1",ifIndex="20",ifName="20"} 1.60948251155615e+14
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 21 on Unit 1",ifIndex="21",ifName="21"} 1.3754296283244e+13
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 22 on Unit 1",ifIndex="22",ifName="22"} 1.7416985946384e+13
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 23 on Unit 1",ifIndex="23",ifName="23"} 4.4569373926096e+13
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 24 on Unit 1",ifIndex="24",ifName="24"} 1.339389886592e+12
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 26 on Unit 1",ifIndex="26",ifName="26"} 0
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 3 on Unit 1",ifIndex="3",ifName="3"} 1.3292564781714e+13
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 7 on Unit 1",ifIndex="7",ifName="7"} 3.27435396e+10
ifHCOutOctets{ifAlias="",ifDescr="D-Link DGS-3420-28TC R1.82.B00 Port 8 on Unit 1",ifIndex="8",ifName="8"} 1.9079625314e+10
```

Comment: `ifIndex="int2"` but your regex tries to search for `ifIndex="digit.."`, is this what you're after [`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/mxRtKs/1/)

Comment: `[1-25]` are you trying to match `1,2,5` digit or you wanted it to be a range from `1 to 25` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

`ifAlias="([^"]+)",.*ifIndex="([^"]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/1120hJ/1

Your ifIndex is looking just for digits `[1-25]` (should be `[0-9]`), where the sample string also contains text

Answer (score 0):

After the double quote there is `int` missing. You could also make the pattern more efficient be using a negated character class between the double quotes `"([^"]*)"`.

When matching `ifIndex="` you match the opening quote, but the closing quote is not matched in the pattern.

Note that 1-25 matches 1, 2 or 5.

```
.*?ifAlias="([^"]*)",.*,ifIndex="(int[1-25][^"]*)".*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J6xqA9/1)

If you only want to match a digit 1 - 25 you could omit the negated character class `[^"]*` matching not a `"` and match the closing `"`:

```
.*?ifAlias="([^"]*)",.*,ifIndex="(int(?:[0-2][0-5]|[1-9]))".*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J6xqA9/2)